# How to switch between monitor speakers and headphones plugged to monitor?

Tags: windows-10, audio, display, hdmi, speakers

I guess there are similar questions here about switching between speakers and headphones on different ports, however, my situation is different.

What I have is a HDMI source connected to my monitor, which has its own speakers. It also has audio out that I have the headphones plugged into. The monitor automatically directs the sound to the headphones if plugged in, only to the speakers if I unplug it.

Is there any easy way to leave the headphones plugged in to the monitor but enable switching between speakers or headphones?

Monitor model is Samsung CF591

Comment: Yeah, I wish monitor manufacturers would implement a simple button in front of the device to switch between headphones and speakers. Usually the headphone jack is located somewhere behind the monitor so it is not easily accessible during use for switching and that would not be the most elegant way anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Most likely not possible.**

My guess is your monitor detects plugged in jack and electrically switches output. There's no software at work, so it's not possible to change in software.

Check monitor's menu - if there's a related switch in there (highly unlikely), then maybe it's also togglable using DDC/CI.

Comment: Hummm ok, so its all hardware controlling not by OS then.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it is a hardware switch inside the Headphone jack that will not allow for switching. Once the switch is engaged, the speakers are disabled. Have you thought about maybe using Bluetooth headphones?

Comment: Thanks. My desktop is an old one that does not have bluetooth.